# Python indent of 4 instead of requested 2

Tags: python, vim

I have

```
syntax on
set pastetoggle=<F3>
set nu
set tabstop=2
set softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set smarttab
set expandtab
set autoindent
set scrolloff=5
set hls 
set incsearch
set history=1000
set nowrap
```

in my .vimrc file and every other file uses 2 spaces when I tab. However, I just started writing python on my computer and it uses 4 spaces. Why is that and how can I turn it back to 2 spaces?

Comment: Well, you really [should](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) be using 4 spaces...

Comment: The PEP 8 standard for python is 4 spaces. You shouldn't change the spacing in python, see here https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: I think an answer should include the fact that python *should* have 4 spaces